# retornar valores de um objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho este objeto no qual preciso pegar a maior parcela com o rate 0 (sem juros) e seu value, e também pegar o maior numero de parcela possível disponível e seu valor.. ja tentei de diversas formas e não consegui, alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
const obj = {
    "hipercard": {
        "total_amount": 187.38,
        "installments": {
            "1": {
                "value": 119.9,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "value": 59.95,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "3": {
                "value": 39.97,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "4": {
                "value": 29.98,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "5": {
                "value": 23.98,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "6": {
                "value": 27.53,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "7": {
                "value": 24.63,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "8": {
                "value": 22.47,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "9": {
                "value": 20.82,
                "rate": 10
            }
        }
    },
      "Amex": {
        "total_amount": 187.38,
        "installments": {
            "1": {
                "value": 119.9,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "2": {
                "value": 59.95,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "3": {
                "value": 39.97,
                "rate": 0
            },
            "4": {
                "value": 29.98,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "5": {
                "value": 23.98,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "6": {
                "value": 27.53,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "7": {
                "value": 24.63,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "8": {
                "value": 22.47,
                "rate": 10
            },
            "9": {
                "value": 20.82,
                "rate": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que vc chama de "parcela"?

Comment: as parcelas são as chaves dentro do installments, "1", "2" ...

Comment: Então queres saber o `value` maior com o `rate: 0` e também o `value` da maior parcela (seria a parcela `9`) independentemente do seu `rate` correto? que nomes lhes queres dar?

Comment: sim, mais nem sempre o valor da parcela maxima vai ser 9, ela pode vir 12x por exemplo...

parcela_sem_juros, valor_sem_juros  || parcela_sem_juros, valor_com_juros

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o `Math.max` para saber o index mais alto. Usando o operador de spread podes passar as parcelas todas ou filtradas por `rate === 0` e saber o index mais alto.

```js
const obj = {"hipercard":{"total_amount":187.38,"installments":{"1":{"value":119.9,"rate":0},"2":{"value":59.95,"rate":0},"3":{"value":39.97,"rate":0},"4":{"value":29.98,"rate":0},"5":{"value":23.98,"rate":0},"6":{"value":27.53,"rate":10},"7":{"value":24.63,"rate":10},"8":{"value":22.47,"rate":10},"9":{"value":20.82,"rate":10}}},"Amex":{"total_amount":187.38,"installments":{"1":{"value":119.9,"rate":0},"2":{"value":59.95,"rate":0},"3":{"value":39.97,"rate":0},"4":{"value":29.98,"rate":10},"5":{"value":23.98,"rate":10},"6":{"value":27.53,"rate":10},"7":{"value":24.63,"rate":10},"8":{"value":22.47,"rate":10},"9":{"value":20.82,"rate":10}}}};

const parcelas = obj.hipercard.installments;

const indexMaisAlto = Math.max(...Object.keys(parcelas));
const parcelaMaisAlta = parcelas[indexMaisAlto];

const indexSemJurosMaisAlto = Math.max(
  ...Object
    .keys(parcelas)
    .filter(index => parcelas[index].rate === 0)
);
const parcelaSemJuroMaisAlta = parcelas[indexSemJurosMaisAlto];

console.log('parcelaMaisAlta', indexMaisAlto, parcelaMaisAlta);
console.log('parcelaSemJuroMaisAlta', indexSemJurosMaisAlto, parcelaSemJuroMaisAlta);
```

Comment: Definitivamente sua solução é mais elaborada e elegante, Mas e se a Amex tiver mais parcelamento ou menos juros? Em sua solução estás considerando apenas o Hiper...

Comment: @JDuwe para evitar "over engineering", ie optimizar no vazio sem ter um caso para aplicar, dei a resposta como está. Se houver mais casos a resposta pode ser modificada. A tua resposta também está limitada a 2 níveis de profundidade de um objeto, e não sabes se todos os objetos respeitam isso.

Comment: Minha resposta respeita o exemplo.

Comment: Exato, a minha também :)

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria desta forma... Não é tão elegante, mas é simples e eficiente.

```js
const obj = {"hipercard":{"total_amount":187.38,"installments":{"1":{"value":119.9,"rate":0},"2":{"value":59.95,"rate":0},"3":{"value":39.97,"rate":0},"4":{"value":29.98,"rate":0},"5":{"value":23.98,"rate":0},"6":{"value":27.53,"rate":10},"7":{"value":24.63,"rate":10},"8":{"value":22.47,"rate":10},"9":{"value":20.82,"rate":10}}},"Amex":{"total_amount":187.38,"installments":{"1":{"value":119.9,"rate":0},"2":{"value":59.95,"rate":0},"3":{"value":39.97,"rate":0},"4":{"value":29.98,"rate":10},"5":{"value":23.98,"rate":10},"6":{"value":27.53,"rate":10},"7":{"value":24.63,"rate":10},"8":{"value":22.47,"rate":10},"9":{"value":20.82,"rate":10}}}};

let maiorParcela = 0;
let valor = 0;
let maiorParcelaSemJuros = 0;
let valorSemJuros = 0;
for (let operadora in obj) {
 for (let parcela in obj[operadora].installments) {
  if (parseInt(parcela) > maiorParcela) {
   maiorParcela = parcela;
   valor = obj[operadora].installments[parcela].value;
  }
  if (obj[operadora].installments[parcela].rate === 0 && parseInt(parcela) > maiorParcelaSemJuros) {
   maiorParcelaSemJuros = parcela;
   valorSemJuros = obj[operadora].installments[parcela].value;
  }
 }
}
console.log(`Em até ${maiorParcelaSemJuros}x de R$${valorSemJuros} sem juros.`);
console.log(`Em até ${maiorParcela}x de R$${valor}.`);
```

Comment: Eu fiz um escopo parecido e acredito que estava errando nas validações.. ja me ajudou demais!

Answer (score 0):

daria para pegar eles pela posição, por exemplo:

```
obj.hipercard.installments[1]
```

irá devolver o um object com o value e o rate, caso você queira só o value ou o rate

```
obj.hipercard.installments[1].value
obj.hipercard.installments[1].rate
```

assim irá pegar separadamente, espero ter ajudado.